# I'm trying to access angular variable through JavaScript. But Its not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using this :

```
window.onload=function(){
    var dom_el2 = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="myCtrl"]');
    var ng_el2 = angular.element(dom_el2);
    var ng_el_scope2 = ng_el2.scope();
    console.log(ng_el_scope2);
    var datan3 = ng_el_scope2.itson;
    console.log(datan3);
      }
```

It is showing value of itson as undefined everytime. I've almost tried all the method. Please Suggest some good method to access angular variable from javascript except using $window.

Comment: Working your way down from `window.onload()` to a specific scope is quite a fragile and un-intuitive way. Why don't you just implement the logic in an **angular controller**, like `myCtrl` (or in a **service** when there is logic used in several controllers)?

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg I'm working on a single page app and I'm using single controller for all my tasks. Thats why i'm preferring somewhat simpler means to do it.

Comment: Please don't do this. It's a bad practice to get into, and basically does an end-run around the AngularJS framework, which presumably you're using for a reason.

Comment: @ShubhamKumarGupta, when you are working on a single page app, DO use angular's mechanics. There is a lot of work, the framework can do for you!

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @MikeMcCaughan, it's a bad practice ! 
But if you really need to do it, here is a simple example with a controller and Vanilla JS to access its variables and functions from outside

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myController" ng-controller="myController as vm">
        My name is {{vm.fullName}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="accessControllerScopeVar()">Get full name</button>  
    <button onclick="accessControllerScopeFunction()">Say hello !</button>   
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular
.module('app')
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.fullName = 'Marty McFly';

    vm.getFullName = function() {
        return vm.fullName;
    }

}]);

function accessControllerScopeVar() {
    var scope = getScopeFor("myController");
    scope.$apply(function () {
        alert(scope.vm.fullName);
    });
}

function accessControllerScopeFunction() {
    var scope = getScopeFor("myController");
    scope.$apply(function () {
        alert('Hello ' + scope.vm.getFullName());
    });
}

function getScopeFor(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var scope = angular.element(el).scope();
    return scope;
}
```

Here is the Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/7U78a6Xdlaef2qOgwucC?p=preview

**Alternative**

If you don't wan't to use ids, here is another sample using `document.querySelector` :

https://plnkr.co/edit/AtAoJhU9zUhYZLC5US5Y?p=preview